# How to feed input into a keras.models() on TF version 2 without tf.compat.v1.Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've trained two models with some data and have they are
`human_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/directory/to/model/human_RNN.h5')
machine_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/directory/to/model/machine_RNN.h5')`

I have a testing set that I want to compare to the two RNNs and want to see if it is more 'human' or more 'machine' with my two LSTMs.

```
def detection(human_model, machine_model, testing_set_to_feed):
    N = test_set_to_feed.len()
    for t in range(1, N-1):
    testing_set_to_feed[t] into first RNN
    likelihood_first <-- prediction(first_rnn)
    testing_set_to_feed[t] into second RNN
    likelihood_second <-- prediction(second_rnn)
    #.....
```

I am on TFv2 so I cannot use get_session(). How do I perform the actual feeding of data into my trained models?

Comment: Have you tried `human_model.predict(testing_set_to_feed)` and `machine_model.predict(testing_set_to_feed)`? the `predict` function will handle the test data 1 by 1 and give you a corresponding prediction for each of them.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't enable as much control as with the old commands. I decided to migrate the code back into TFv1